# where does kernel store processes which are not running?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, task

everyone I have some question about tasks in Linux, I know that all tasks which are currently at the state `TASK_RUNNING` are in data structure called `runqueue`, but what about the tasks which are waiting for some event (states which are not TASK_RUNNING, for example one which is waiting for the input from keyboard). Do I have some other data structure for such tasks or only general `list of tasks`? thanks in advance for any explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processes in a `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` or `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` state are further subdivided in to different classes, each of which corresponds to a specific event. In this state, the process state does not provide enough info to retrieve the process descriptor quickly, so another list of processes called `wait_queue` are used. Wait_queue implements conditional waits on events. A process waiting for a specific event is placed in the proper wait queue.

Wait queues are implemented as cyclical lists whose elements include pointers to process 
descriptors. Each element of a wait queue list is of type wait_queue:

```
struct wait_queue {  
    struct task_struct * task;  
    struct wait_queue * next;  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

wait queues are used to enable processes to wait for a particular event to occur - such as waiting for input from a keyboard.